# MongoDB automatically replace &lt with <

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, html-escape-characters

i want to replace all < in a string with &lt and insert it into MongoDB.
But when i insert it, MongoDB automatically replace &lt with <.
How can i do to prevent it?
This is the code for replace all < with the escaping quote:

```
let desc;

splitDesc.forEach(element => {
   if(element == "<") {
        desc += "&lt";
   } else if(element != "<") {
        desc += element;
   }
});
```

Comment: &amp would never be replaced with <.   I could see &lt getting converted to <, or &amp converted to &, but that makes no sense. You probably have a different error

Comment: @GarrGodfrey oh yes sorry.
I have the same problem with &lt.

Comment: you may need to show more code, like your actual update. I'm concerned by your `else` statement, since the `if` is unnecessary. Is it possible the `&lt` is converted to `<` only when you view it, if you are viewing in a web browser?

Comment: since `desc` starts out as `undefined`, it will still be `undefined` even after appending to it. So this code actually does nothing.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey I think it'd just coerce `undefined` to a string; you'd end up with a string prefixed by `"undefined"` plus everything else appended to it.

Comment: Thanks i have resolved the problem!